# Generating hash of a class structure in C#

Tags: c#, hash, roslyn

Our application makes use of serialized snapshots of state which is just a serialized version of the class at a point in time.

We have a version number on the class which we increment each time the class is modified which we use to indicate that the previous snapshots are invalid and to ignore them.

Occasionally someone forgets to increment the version and we get errors.

I'd like to generate a hash for the structure of the class and use that to store snapshots, so if it ever changes then the previous snapshots would automatically invalidated.

I've though about using Roslyn to load a representation of the class and call GetHashCode on that but can't work out how to load an existing class into Roslyn.

Also I've looked into Visual Studio generating hashes at build time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/visual-studio-hashing-source-code-files-with-visual-studio-to-assure-file-integrity but this seems like overkill.

So how do I generate a hash of an existing C# class structure (not an instance of a class)?

Update:

This is a POCO with no methods. Changes that invalidate snapshot include adding, removing or renaming properties.

Comment: What kind of changes would invalidate your snapshot? Only changes to fields or also changes to method declarations or even changes to the implementation?

Comment: How about serialising into a format that doesn't care about extra properties, like JSON?  If V1 has 2 properties (name, address) and V2 has 3 properties (name, address, dob), then JSON will serialise the same data into both, without any problems.

Comment: If someone forgets to update the version number then that sounds to me you are missing a unittest case for that.

Comment: You could use a [Source Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview). You could make your class a partial class. The generator would create a second partial class file containing an attribute on the class or a string constant with the hash code.

Comment: A balance will have to be struck between invalidating the class on every compilation (even if there was no change), and something more conservative to ignore the class getting some kind of change which is not necessarily significant. Changing a number every time the class is changed in any way is the simplest (and the most conservative), but this would also count changes that are invisible or insignificant to outside observers (adding comments, adding a private field to cache data, adding an attribute to a property), which may not be desirable.

Comment: @PMF updated the question to clarify

Comment: @Neil we already have our serialization format defined and cannot change it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using reflection to get that.

Something along the lines of:

```cs
private int GetHashOfClass(Type myType)
{
    int hash = 0;
    foreach (var f in myType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        if (f.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field ||
            (f.MemberType & MemberTypes.Property) != 0)
        {
            hash ^= CreateHash(f.Name);
        }

        if (f is FieldInfo fi)
        {
            hash ^= CreateHash(fi.FieldType.Name);
        }
    }

    return hash;
}
```

That generates a hashcode from the fields and properties of a class. `CreateHash` is just a function that generates a hash from a string. Do *not* use the existing `string.GetHashCode`, because the result of that function will change each time the application is started.

Comment: We started with this as a base but noted that nested objects need to be checked too so made the method recursive. Also generate the hash based on Type and Name in case a data type changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonSchema (from NJsonSchema nuget):

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

string schema = JsonSchema.FromType<T>().ToJson();
//{
//  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
//  "title": "Person",
//  "type": "object",
//  "additionalProperties": false,
//  "required": [
//    "FirstName",
//    "LastName"
//  ],
//  "properties": {
//    "FirstName": {
//      "type": "string"
//    },
//    "MiddleName": {
//      "type": [
//        "null",
//        "string"
//      ]
//    },
//    "LastName": {
//      "type": "string"
//    }
//  }
//}
```